# How to add image name with extension to hyperlink trailing end php

Tags: php, download, endpoint

Am trying to figure out how does one make myimage.jpg part of the trail end point of an hyperlink?

So far I have got the image to download but not sure how to make the hyperlink look like:

```
http://192.168.0.11/myimage.jpg
```

My code so far:

```
<?php

$file = "./my_image.jpg";

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `echo` to print your `$file` variable at the end of your link.

Like this,

```
<a href="//192.168.0.11/<?php echo $file; ?>">
```

This will create the link look this in `HTML`,

```
<a href="//192.168.0.11/myimage.jpg">
```

Comment: thank you. I am not wanting to pass to the HTML though. Am wanting to consume the image using Glide in Android. Currently it does fetch the image and display it.

Comment: Yes once I removed the headers as it was downloading rather than displaying it.

Comment: When I had a look in the HTML page just to see what kind of output its getting from the PHP. I got: <a href="//192.168.0.11/<?php echo ./myimage.jpg ?>"> I invoked the file by: <?php include_once('imageurl.php');?>